# Adding noise to a matrix/vector

Tags: r, error

How to add noise to an object, regardless of the amount of dimensions?

I would expect to try to use some sort of `apply` to add noise of the type:

`runif(1, -0.00001, 0.0001)` for each cell.

What I tried before was to have a matrix of r * c, and then creating a matrix with noise, and add them together. It works, but I believe there is a more general solution (and I am interesting in how `apply` could solve this)

As a side question, should we add uniform errors or normally distributed errors?

EDIT: The reason is that I am trying to do bootstraps, and my distributions are heavily skewed. An overrepresentation of 1's. The problem is that, when I am trying to do cross-validations, sometimes I end up doing an

`lm(Y ~ X1, X2)`

In which there is no variance (all 1's), and therefore it can't compute and gives an `NA`.
However, this is not good for bootstrapping anymore, because these errors are messing up what is "really" going on. I figured adding noise allows the linear model to run, since there will not be 0 variance any more?

Comment: why do you want to use apply?

Comment: @user603 I have the idea it might be a quick way to "apply" one different sample of the uniform distribution to all cells of an object with any dimensions/length

Comment: The side question makes this thread on topic here.  (Otherwise, it would be purely about `R` programming, which would be migrated to SO.)  However, it's not possible to answer the side question without more information: **why** are you adding noise to your matrix? What is it intended to represent or model?

Comment: Although adding the noise will make `lm` run, your attempted "bootstrap" may then give answers that depend *arbitrarily* on the noise. The `NA` values are a clear sign that the particular bootstrap you are attempting may be invalid or give misleading results. Please consider rethinking your analytical strategy rather than papering over its deficiencies with this artificial fix-up.  Perhaps you could instead ask a question in which you describe your data and what you are trying to learn about them, point out the problem with the bootstrap, and ask about alternative approaches.

Comment: I was doing a simulation study on real data, trying to find out how large a sample size should be to be able to do a 5-fold crossvalidation, and not have really high mean squared errors. That is, resampling from a (n = 7000) study. The problem with taking small sample sizes and many 1's, is that indeed some bootstraps don't compute.

Comment: Oh, and then I figured that it might work with adding noise. But, correct me if I am wrong, the lm results would then be based on noise. Wouldn't it be possible to add noise that would not influence the lm result?

Comment: Probably not right, because the only way the linear model would stay intact correctly, is when the errors added to 1s are all the same, and then it won't compute.

Comment: Shouldn't a cv be based on the residuals? I.e. maybe I missed something but from your description, it seems to me that you are bootstrapping the (Y_i,X_i) when you should be bootraping the e_i's

Comment: I am taking the coefficients of a first prediction (training sample) and use them on a test section, within this data.

Comment: I posted a $1-$line code doing exactly what you were asking for (A function that takes as an argument either a scalar, a vector or a matrix and adds random noise using a previously chosen distribution). Since the question seems to be evolving every time an answer (excepts yours) appears, I am deleting mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my answer so far, though I do not think it's the best code ever written.

```
Noisify <- function(data) {

  if (is.vector(data)) {
    noise <- runif(length(data), -0.00001, 0.00001)
    noisified <- data + noise
  } else {
    length <- dim(data)[1] * dim(data)[2]
    noise <- matrix(runif(length, -0.0001, 0.00001), dim(data)[1])
    noisified <- data + noise
  }
  return(noisified)
}
```

Comment: Looks legit. :) You might reconsider using `return()`. Removing that (and just leaving the object, like I did in my answer) may give you some performance boost, especially if you have a lot of `return` calls.

Comment: I don't know why, but it did not return the last created object?

Comment: You could avoid defining all those variables in the function by writing the function as `Noisify <- function(data) {
  if (is.vector(data)) return( data + runif(length(data), -0.00001, 0.00001))
  else return(data + matrix(runif(dim(data)[1] * dim(data)[2], -0.0001, 0.00001), dim(data)[1]))
}`.

Comment: agreed, i'll update it soon

Answer (score 3):

@whuber makes excellent point regarding the goal of this endeavour, but here's a idea of how to proceed. The idea is to add each cell a corresponding amount of generated noise.

```
> my.data <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
> my.data
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> random.stuff <- matrix(runif(prod(dim(my.data)), min = -0.00001, max = 0.0001), nrow = 3)
> random.stuff 
             [,1]          [,2]         [,3]
[1,] 8.488258e-05 -4.608706e-06 1.869516e-05
[2,] 2.100283e-05  8.500601e-05 7.376338e-05
[3,] 7.625872e-05  6.188059e-05 4.424394e-05
> random.stuff + my.data
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1.000085 3.999995 7.000019
[2,] 2.000021 5.000085 8.000074
[3,] 3.000076 6.000062 9.000044
```

This function takes in a matrix and adds some random noise.

```
addNoise <- function(mtx) {
  if (!is.matrix(mtx)) mtx <- matrix(mtx, byrow = TRUE, nrow = 1)
  random.stuff <- matrix(runif(prod(dim(mtx)), min = -0.00001, max = 0.0001), nrow = dim(mtx)[1])
  random.stuff + mtx
}

> new.data <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10)
> addNoise(mtx = new.data)
           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
 [1,]  1.000002 11.00003 21.00001 31.00001 41.00004 51.00009 61.00004 71.00004 81.00002 90.99999
 [2,]  2.000002 11.99999 22.00004 32.00000 42.00006 52.00009 62.00000 72.00008 82.00001 92.00001
 [3,]  3.000069 13.00006 23.00003 33.00010 43.00004 53.00005 63.00009 73.00005 83.00008 93.00000
 [4,]  4.000088 14.00003 24.00006 34.00009 44.00002 54.00002 64.00007 74.00003 84.00007 94.00010
 [5,]  5.000073 15.00007 25.00002 35.00009 45.00001 55.00004 65.00002 75.00010 85.00006 95.00000
 [6,]  6.000062 16.00001 26.00002 36.00002 46.00008 56.00007 66.00002 76.00000 86.00006 96.00009
 [7,]  7.000007 17.00003 27.00005 37.00007 47.00002 57.00000 67.00006 77.00000 87.00007 97.00000
 [8,]  8.000019 18.00009 27.99999 37.99999 48.00003 58.00009 68.00001 77.99999 88.00003 98.00001
 [9,]  8.999995 19.00010 29.00007 39.00004 49.00008 59.00004 69.00008 79.00005 89.00001 99.00002
[10,] 10.000015 20.00007 30.00003 40.00009 50.00004 60.00009 70.00002 80.00002 90.00003 99.99999
```

Here's an example of working on vectors. Output will be a 1 by x matrix.

```
> new.data <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 1)
> addNoise(mtx = new.data)
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
[1,] 1.000091 2.000014 2.999991 4.000047 5.000056 6.000042 6.999998 8.000097 9.000066 10.00008
```

Added some code to show how `return()` seems to slow down code.

```
library(rbenchmark)
addNoise <- function(mtx) {
  if (!is.matrix(mtx)) mtx <- matrix(mtx, byrow = TRUE, nrow = 1)
  random.stuff <- matrix(runif(prod(dim(mtx)), min = -0.00001, max = 0.0001), nrow = dim(mtx)[1])
  out <- random.stuff + mtx
  out
}

addNoiseReturn <- function(mtx) {
  if (!is.matrix(mtx)) mtx <- matrix(mtx, byrow = TRUE, nrow = 1)
  random.stuff <- matrix(runif(prod(dim(mtx)), min = -0.00001, max = 0.0001), nrow = dim(mtx)[1])
  out <- random.stuff + mtx
  return(out)
}

new.data <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10)
benchmark(replications = rep(10000, 1),
          noReturn = addNoise(new.data),
          withReturn = addNoiseReturn(new.data))
        test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1   noReturn        10000    0.19    1.000      0.19        0         NA        NA
2 withReturn        10000    0.22    1.158      0.22        0         NA        NA
```

Comment: You describe the method that I already used, but what if we want a general function to do this, for any dimension sizes? When you don't want to manually have to fill in the amount of rows etc.

Comment: I've added a function, is this what you're after?

Comment: No, because you can't use this function for any other data, say a 10 by 10 matrix.

Comment: I think it's OK now. I've added an example.

Comment: Still missing the option to add it to a vector, I mean...please read the question again.

Comment: What do you mean by "add it to a vector"? Using `apply` in this context would be like reaching for your left pocket with your right hand.

Comment: My mistake, I meant that this function should also take vectors as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand the question. The '+' function in R does this already.

```
> a<-matrix(1:12,nr=3)
> b<-rnorm(12)  # b is a vector
> a+b           # R adds b to a as a matrix
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 1.144552 4.946283 8.026290 11.40905
[2,] 1.038299 5.752317 7.544441 10.78278
[3,] 3.173348 5.574810 9.805634 13.65378
```

What do you actually need a function for, that this doesn't do?

Comment: I don't understand actually why people have a trouble understanding that with this you have to set the length of the rnorm. I'd like to  just pass data of any kind to a function and that's it.

Comment: `b<-rnorm(prod(dim(a)))`. Was that really the problem?

Comment: If you have a vector, `dim` won't work.

Comment: `b<-rnorm(prod(dim(as.array(a))))`?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `jitter` from `base` package, and which adds a small amount of noise to a numeric vector.